# Spring Security content-security-policy for web services

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, content-security-policy

I have my security context like below:

```xml
<http entry-point-ref="serviceEntryPoint" pattern="/service/.*" use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex" create-session="never">        
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/.*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SUPER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <custom-filter position="TEST" ref="myCustomFilter" />
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <content-security-policy>frame-ancestors 'self'</content-security-policy>
    </headers>
    <intercept-url pattern="/forgot.ajax" access="permitAll" />
        ........
        ........
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

I have added the `content-security-policy` tag to one of the `http` sections. Do I need to include the `content-security-policy` for the service layer too?

Comment: Do you expose that `service` via http/web service, or it is just internally used by our web layer?

Comment: Internally used by the web layer.